# Call a button event from a function

Tags: c#, winforms, keyboard

I want to call a button event in a function as shown below, This might not be the right way. If you have idea how to go around this please share some sample on how to achieve it.
Thanks

```
 protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData) 
    {
        const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100;
        const int WM_SYSKEYDOWN = 0x104;

        if ((msg.Msg == WM_KEYDOWN) || (msg.Msg == WM_SYSKEYDOWN))
        {
            switch (keyData)
            {
              case Keys.Down:
              button4_Click(sender, e); //error: sender and e does not exist in the current context
              break;
            }
        }

        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
```

Comment: Are you using WPF, WinForms?

Comment: Sorry for that...I'm using Winforms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do not move `button4_Click` code to other method like `ProcessSomething()` and do processing there. Then just change

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData) 
{
    const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100;
    const int WM_SYSKEYDOWN = 0x104;

    if ((msg.Msg == WM_KEYDOWN) || (msg.Msg == WM_SYSKEYDOWN))
    {
        switch (keyData)
        {
          case Keys.Down:
          ProcessSomething();
          break;
        }
    }

    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

you can fire `button4_Click` method by passing nulls to it but IMO it is not elegant to fire events like that.

Comment: Agreed. Treating event handlers in user code as functions is abuse.

Comment: Thanks gzaxx. Just to clear things up Grant, I am new to programming. So is it not ok to call an event like a function? what are the implications? I have used a lot of them in my program

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData) 
{
    const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100;
    const int WM_SYSKEYDOWN = 0x104;

    if ((msg.Msg == WM_KEYDOWN) || (msg.Msg == WM_SYSKEYDOWN))
    {
        switch (keyData)
        {
          case Keys.Down:
          button4_Click(null, null);
          break;
        }
    }

    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Call `button4 click` passing itself as sender and new `System EventArgs` as second parameter:

```
button4_Click(button4, new System.EventArgs());
```